# How to calculate remainder when $15^{43}-3^{23}$ is divided by $14$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to calculate the remainder when $15^{43}-3^{23}$ is divided by $14$.

Using what I know already, I got that:

$$15^{43} \equiv 1 \mod 14$$

$$3^{23} \equiv 5 \mod 14$$

and so I should have that

$$15^{43}-3^{23} \equiv (-4)\bmod14$$ but this is not right so I don't really know what to do, I can't see any error in my calculations?

Any ideas?

Comment: $-4\equiv10\pmod{15}$....

Comment: How does this make no sense? Remember that $-4\equiv -4 + k\cdot14 (\text{mod} 14)∀k\inℤ$, which gives you $-4\equiv 10 (\text{mod} 14)$

Comment: But then the remainder would be $10$ but according to Wolfram Alpha it is 3.

Comment: @Hugo No, [it is 10.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15^43-3^23+mod+14)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $-4 \equiv 10 \mod 14$.

Comment: But then the remainder would be $10$ but according to Wolfram Alpha it is 3.

Comment: Check [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%5E%2843%29+-+3%5E%2823%29+mod+14)

Comment: Oh thanks! Guess I must have entered in something wrong and it tried to calculate something else. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $15^{43}-3^{23}>0$

So, the reminder will be $\ge0$

You have already found $15^{43}\equiv1\pmod{14}$

and as $3^3\equiv-1\pmod{14},3^{23}=3^2(3^3)^7\equiv3^2(-1)^7\equiv-9\pmod{14}$

Comment: @Hugo, How about this?

Answer (score 0):

Since $15\equiv1\pmod{14}$, you know that $15^k\equiv1\pmod{14}$ for any (non negative) integer $k$.

Since $\gcd(3,14)=1$, we can apply Euler-Fermat: $\varphi(14)=6$, so $3^6\equiv1\pmod{14}$. Now $23=3\cdot6+5$, so
$$
3^{23}=(3^6)^3\cdot 3^5\equiv 3^5\pmod{14}
$$
Now it's just computation, but if we note that $3\cdot 5\equiv1\pmod{14}$, we have
$$
3^5\equiv 3^5\cdot3\cdot5\equiv 3^6\cdot 5\equiv 5\pmod{14}
$$
Thus
$$
15^{43}-3^{23}\equiv1-5\equiv10\pmod{14}
$$

Answer (score 0):

${\rm mod}\,\ 14\!:\ \ \color{#c00}{15\equiv 1},\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{3^3\equiv -1}$

$\qquad\ \Rightarrow \ \ \color{#c00}{15}^J- {3^{\large 2} (\color{#0a0}{3^{\large 3}})^{ K}},\ \ \ K$ odd

$\qquad\ \equiv\quad \color{#c00}1^J - 9\,(\color{#0a0}{-1})^{K}\equiv\, 10\quad $ by $ $ [Congruence Arithmetic Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)